# Centering my image inside my div

Tags: css

How can I have my image centered horizontally (and if possible vertically also) ?

HTML

```
<div class="wholeHeight">
    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" class="ajustImageToScreenResolution">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wholeHeight 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.ajustImageToScreenResolution 
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0exjyfz5/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: use this http://jsfiddle.net/0exjyfz5/7/ set the image absolute and position it top and left 50% and transform it by giving -50% top and left

Answer (score 1):

The best way out would be:

```
<div class="wholeHeight">
    <div class ="myImage">
    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" class="ajustImageToScreenResolution">
        </div>
</div>

.wholeHeight {
  position: relative;
}
.myImage{

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, +50%);
}
.ajustImageToScreenResolution 
{

    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/0exjyfz5/8/

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this I made some changes in the css will help you

```
<div class="wholeHeight">
    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" class="ajustImageToScreenResolution">
</div>

wholeHeight 
{
   text-align:center;  
}
.ajustImageToScreenResolution 
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To center it vertically put the image in a div, make the div the same height and width as the image, and set both "margin-left" and "margin-right" to auto for the div. This will center it vertically.

Answer (score -1):

Please add the following code.

```html
<center><div class="wholeHeight">
    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" class="ajustImageToScreenResolution">
</div></center>
```

Thanks is always appreciated.

Comment: The `center` tag is deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center.